# Escaping in a Bash extended pattern @(..)

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching, glob

I stumbled across "Extended pattern" extglob for Bash. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern

I'm investigating this case:

Imagine a directory structure like this:

```
/basedir/2017/02/26/uniquedirs1/files.log 
/basedir/2017/02/27/uniquedirs2/files.log 
/basedir/2017/02/28/uniquedirs3/files.log 
/basedir/2017/03/01/uniquedirs4/files.log
/basedir/2017/03/02/uniquedirs5/files.log
```

If I'd like to list the files of the directory `2017/02/27` and `2017/02/28` I can simply write:

```
ls /basedir/2017/02/@("27"|"28")/*/files.log
```

Awesome! \o/

Now the question. How can I define multiple directories in a Bash extended pattern?
This doesn't work:

```
ls /basedir/2017/@("02/28"|"03/01")/*/files.log
ls /basedir/2017/@("02\/28"|"03\/01")/*/files.log
```

Is there any way I can get to define multiple directories for "Extended pattern"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pathname generation only applies patterns to pathname components; they never match the `/` that separates components. Brace expansion would be cleaner here:

```
ls /basedir/2017/{2/28,3/01}/*/files.log
```

which would first expand to

```
ls /basedir/2017/2/28/*/files.log /basedir/2017/3/01/*/files.log
```

before performing pathname generation on the two resulting patterns.

Comment: The only problem with a brace expansion though is that I can't define the range dynamically.

Comment: You can't with extended patterns, either, so you aren't losing anything :)

Comment: Ok. that's a shame... I'm still no closer to an efficient solution. The only problem I have though is that a brace expansion can't be defined dynamically. like `var1="02/28,03/01" ls /basedir/2017/"$var1"/*/files.log` unless I execute it in a subshell. But this works: `var2="27|28" ls /basedir/2017/02/@("$var2")/*/files.log`

Answer (score 0):

ok, the way I've solved this dynamically, is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# User input:
start_date="2017-02-27"
day_range=2

# Logic:

declare -a 'date_range=($( echo {'"$day_range"'..0} | xargs -I{} -d " " date -d "'"$start_date"' +{} day" --rfc-3339="date" ))'
#this creates an array with dates:
#2017-03-02 2017-03-01 2017-02-28 2017-02-27

eval ls "basedir/{$(IFS=\, ; echo "${date_range[*]//-//}")}/*/files.log"
#this translates to:
#ls basedir/{2017/03/01,2017/02/28,2017/02/27}/*/files.log
```

This is more useful if you want to use it with tools like grep to fetch data if you can't use file-creation-dates.